# Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Problem 1 vi

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm starting to make my way through Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (3rd edition) and have somehow gotten stuck on one of the first problems.

The problem (on page 13) is:

(vi) Prove the following: $x^{3} + y^{3} = (x + y)(x^{2} - xy + y^{2})$

It also has a hint saying that there is a particularly easy way of doing this using one of the previous questions (iv). Apparently this way shows a way to factorize $x^{n} + y^{n}$ when $n$ is odd.

I could just expand $(x + y)(x^{2} -xy + y^{2})$ and cancel out the middle terms, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it per the hint. Question (iv) was to prove $x^{3} - y^{3} = (x - y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2})$.

My first approach was to add $y^{3} - y^{3}$ to the left hand side so that:
$$\begin{align}
x^{3} + y^{3} + y^{3} - y^{3} &= (x^{3} - y^{3}) + y^{3} + y^{3} \\
&= (x - y)(x^{2} + xy + y^{2}) + y^{3} + y^{3} \\
\end{align}$$

But at that point I'm probably barking up the wrong tree.

The book then says the answer is to replace $y$ in (iv) with $-y$, but I'm not understanding how or why.

Any help?

Comment: This is a problematic problem in Spivak's book, because to do problems with $\cdots$ in them really requires induction or at least summation symbols, and those don't show up until the next chapter. The fifteen times I taught out of this wonderful book, I never quite knew how to handle this issue without just saying "you know what he means."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $x^3+y^3=x^3-(-y)^3$.